# Have you been saving money?

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense, spoken-english

> Me: Have you been saving money lately?

> Peter: No, I haven't.

If I ask Peter again: "do you save money?", is it possible for him to answer, "yes, I do"?

> Me: Do you save money?

> John: No, I don't.

If I ask John again: "have you been saving money lately", is it possible for him to say "yes, I have"?

Answer (score 2):

It would be rather strange to ask either of those "follow-up" questions unless you are more specific about exactly what information you are looking for.

If someone "hasn't been saving money lately," then it's strange to ask "do you save money," because that is a very general question, and you already have some specific information. It would make more sense to say something like "in the past, did you regularly save money?" If you did ask such a question, one would expect Peter to clarify in his response that, although he just said he hasn't been saving money lately, he used to in the past. "I do save money" includes the recent past, and he just said that he didn't save in the recent past, so it would be somewhat contradictory without further explanation.

Even more strongly, if someone "doesn't save money," that is fairly absolute, and asking if they have been saving lately is *very* strange: they just said that they don't save! And John saying that he has been saving recently is plainly a contradiction to the fact that he "doesn't save."

Comment: My understanding is diffeent. Lately I haven't been saving money, because I have been spending too much. But I do save money. It is my habit, which allows a temporary breaking. Is my understanding possible?

Comment: @Stephen if you intend that meaning, you have to specify it, otherwise it sounds very strange.

Comment: Another native speaker commented: "He saves money" implies that he does habitually save money. If he usually saves money but he skipped last month, then there's no contradiction. He hasn't saved any money recently but he usually does.

Comment: "haven't saved recently" doesn't imply "last month" unless you specify that. If you meant "last month" say "last month", recently means in general. As I said, it might be possible, but it would sound very strange without further explanation.

Comment: Sorry to disagree. Yes, you're right, "recently" doesn't imply "last month". It means "recently". But if he hasn't saved money recently, that doesn't mean he doesn't save money. As I said, common sense tells us that some people do save money, but there is a temporary break recently due to a variety of reasons.

Comment: @Stephen of course that is possible. What I was saying is that *if* you meant to ask/answer about that case specifically, you *should* specify that, because otherwise it seems strange or confusing. We try not to be confusing and make people think twice about what we're asking/saying usually.